# Efficiently set a list of pixels value in python?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

How can i set a list of pixels efficiently using python.

For example if i have:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((700, 200, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

l = [[300, 101], [200, 102], [150, 103], [300, 104], [88, 105], [66, 106], [666, 107]]
```

i just want to set pixels with *l* coordinates to black color.

I know i can do something like this:

```
for p in l:
    img[p[0], p[1]] = (0, 0, 0)
```

I wonder if there is something more efficient.

Comment: why do you have a list in the first place? where is it from? having a list of pixels is generally a bad idea and there are better representations in most cases.

Comment: As those points are independent, I doubt that there is a significantly better way.

Comment: `img[tuple(zip(*l))] = 0`

Comment: l=np.array(l); a[l[:,1],l[:,0],:]=0

Comment: one of you please post that as an answer or flag as duplicate of some other question

Answer (score -1):

Your example is confusing (at least for me :D ) but I think this might be more "efficient"

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#an array:

img=255*np.ones((700,700,3),dtype=np.uint8)

list = [[444, 101], [200, 102], [150, 103], [300, 104], [88, 105], [66, 106], [666, 107]]
```

#with for loop

```
def set_pixels(img, list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        x = list[i][0]
        y = list[i][1]
        img[x, y] = [0, 0, 0]
```

without for loop (Alex Alex mentioned)

```
def set_pixels_2(img, list):
    list = np.array(list)
    img[list[:,0], list[:,1]] = [0, 0, 0]
set_pixels(img, list)
set_pixels2(img, list)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: that's even worse. answering this question properly requires more than an introductory knowledge of numpy.